# how to pass more than one web elements to page using phantomjs

Tags: java, phantomjs, testng

I am trying to use phantomjs for testing, I have one login page with obvious two parameters **username** and **password**. If i try same code with google url where i have to pass only one element with and say element.submit(); but in my login page i want to pass two elements how to achieve the same ?

here is my code -

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class PhantomExample {

    public PhantomExample() {
        System.out.println("this is constructor");
    }
    @Test
    public void verify() {
        File src = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\Compressed\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities phantomjsCap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        phantomjsCap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        phantomjsCap.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());

        System.out.println("inside the verify method");
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(phantomjsCap);
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Login");
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        WebElement el =driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        WebElement elp =driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        el.sendKeys("username");
        elp.sendKeys("0");
        el.submit();
        elp.submit();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        File Ss=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(Ss, new File("d:/sample.jpg"));

            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }
        driver.quit();
    }    
}
```

Here i created two separate elements and expecting to get the response, but when i run it in debugger mode it is not executing after line el.submit();

I am quite sure that i am doing this wrong way, but can someone tell me what is the right approach to this and explain how to get response object which server would send after log in ?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `submit()` method on an input field submits **the whole form** (with all input values), so the following line can be deleted:

```
    elp.submit();
```

If the form has a submit button, then after executing `el.submit()` login will be done.